# Chrome extension background XMLHttpRequest proxy server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a background task in a Chrome Extension that performs some polling/checking. In error cases, I want to retry the check using a different CDN server to verify if it's a site-wide problem or just a CDN node affected. The challenge is how to control to which CDN node to send to.

e.g. let's say I'm checking www.company.com and typically that will be served by server21.cdn.co

Now if that fails I want to check server5.cdn.co and server10.cdn2.co for the same content to see if there's a correlation.

These checks are done using XMLHttpRequest but I can't find a way to specify which host/proxy to use per-request.

I wouldn't want to "hijack" the entire browser's proxy server settings because it would cause all other pages/tabs to fail.

Comment: What proxy and server settings? AFAIK there's no way for a requester to control which CDN server is used. It's something that the CDN decides itself because this is the entire point of CDN, isn't it?

Comment: The point of this requirement is to check the CDN. I know what the IP addresses of the CDN nodes are, I don't need to query DNS for those. I just need to be able to control which IP is used to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's load-balancing performed on the DNS level (which is most probable), you can't affect which server you actually contact at all.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're meaning by "that". i.e. you mean specifically that you can't control the proxy server that XMLHttpRequest uses?

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, and elaborate myself. This can't be done because XMLHTTPRequest forbids overriding the Host header. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46702/how-can-i-control-the-content-of-the-http-host-header-in-requests-issued-from-my/. Possible to do via `curl` though, if I weren't stuck inside a Chrome Extension: https://drewish.com/2010/03/29/using-curl-and-the-host-header-to-bypass-a-load-balancer/

Comment: @rgareth I wouldn't mind upvoting if you posted that as a second answer

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, this can't be done because XMLHTTPRequest forbids overriding the `Host` header in requests. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46702/how-can-i-control-the-content-of-the-http-host-header-in-requests-issued-from-my/ for an explanation of why.

Conceptually/technically it's easy to do if it weren't for this security issue. For example with `curl`:
    curl --verbose --header 'Host: www.example.com' 'http://10.1.1.36/the_url_to_test'

But as mentioned in the question, we're stuck inside a Chrome extension so `curl` is not an option!